# Twitter app: Is it possible to switch accounts while viewing a tweet?

Tags: twitter

I have the Twitter app for Android, and I use 2 accounts. Both are configured in the app.

How can I switch accounts while viewing a single tweet (if, for instance, I'm viewing a tweet in account A but want to retweet it from account B).

I used to be able to do it, but they seem to have removed it a few updates ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current version (Version 8.25.1-release.0 on Dec 20, 2019), **it is not possible to switch accounts while viewing a tweet on the official Twitter app**.

The only way to switch account is from the sidebar, and it is currently only accessible from the main screen.

Instead, to "retweet from another account", the native workaround is by sending a *direct message* to that account:

1. From a specific tweet, tap the "Share Tweet"
2. Choose "Send via Direct Message" and choose the target account
3. Go back to the main screen, then switch to another account
4. Navigate to "Messages" (mail icon on the bottom navigation bar), then open the conversation with another account
5. Open the tweet, then retweet.

(Note: to reduce the switching, it is recommended to bulk send the tweets first before switching)